# GUID as PK or as index only?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

We want to have our client apps to be able to generate identifiers for objects they create.

We have 2 options to implement that:

1. Have GUID (generated by client) as PK, non-clustered and at the same time have AUTO_INCREMENT int column with clustered index on it for later, under the hood usage mainly in JOINS
2. Abandon AUTO_INCREMENT column completely

We are not worried about storage space.

Is there any significant gain going with option 1, or in other words, anything problematic with option 2?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but regardless of where you ask this, its a highly opinionated topic, and not easily quantifiable without exact examples of usage.

Comment: you might be right. btw, when you added option 3, why would you prefer unique index over PK? sounds like in that case I would try to enforce something that PK already does.

Comment: oh, you meant Guid not being PK. I have read that as table not having PK at all. Could you please confirm that is what you mean: PK on int and  guid as unique index?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Please post as answer if you want so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement:

> We want to have our client apps to be able to generate identifiers for objects they create.

I would suggest you have a regular int/bigint identity column primary key as this typically performs better than a uniqueidentifier.

And then add a surrogate GUID (uniqueidentifier) column, which would be indexed as a unique, non-clustered index.

This gives you the best of both worlds. A well performing primary key, and the ability to assign identifiers to your objects client side.